# Как выравнить текст кнопки на одну линию с текстом рядом с кнопкой?

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.cover {
  height: 757px;
  color: #fff;
  background-image: url(https://i.ibb.co/s6kGSxv/cover.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
}

.cover_wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 530px;
  margin: 165px 50px 62px 50px;
}

.ono_tebe_nado {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 15px;
}

.letter-spacing_60 {
  letter-spacing: 60px;
}

.letter-spacing_0 {
  letter-spacing: 0px;
}

.aligned-text {
  display: flex;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 100px;
  line-height: 115%;
  letter-spacing: 30px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.aligned-text_center {
  display: flex;
  align-self: center;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 100px;
  line-height: 115%;
  letter-spacing: 30px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.aligned-text_right {
  display: flex;
  align-self: end;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 100px;
  line-height: 115%;
  letter-spacing: 30px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.make_bet {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  align-items: flex-end;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 22px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.bet-button {
  justify-self: end;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  padding: 12px 32px;
}

.bet_text {
  padding-right: 100px;
  line-height: 28px;
  word-spacing: 17px;
}
```

```html
<section class="cover overlay">
  <div class="cover_wrapper">
    <div class="ono_tebe_nado">
      <div class="aligned-text">О<span class="letter-spacing_60">но</span></div>
      <div class="aligned-text_center">те<span class="letter-spacing_60">бе</span></div>
      <div class="aligned-text_right"><span class="letter-spacing_60">н</span>ад<span class="letter-spacing_0">о</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="make_bet">
      <div class="bet-button">Сделать ставку</div>
      <div class="bet_text">Аукцион вещей, в которые никто не верил</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: .make_bet { align-items: center; }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться `align-items: center;` (в данном случае задаст выравнивание по вертикали):

```css
.cover {
  height: 757px;
  color: #fff;
  background-image: url(https://i.ibb.co/s6kGSxv/cover.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
}

.cover_wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 530px;
  margin: 165px 50px 62px 50px;
}

.ono_tebe_nado {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 15px;
}

.letter-spacing_60 {
  letter-spacing: 60px;
}

.letter-spacing_0 {
  letter-spacing: 0px;
}

.aligned-text {
  display: flex;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 100px;
  line-height: 115%;
  letter-spacing: 30px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.aligned-text_center {
  display: flex;
  align-self: center;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 100px;
  line-height: 115%;
  letter-spacing: 30px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.aligned-text_right {
  display: flex;
  align-self: end;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 100px;
  line-height: 115%;
  letter-spacing: 30px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.make_bet {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  /* new */
  align-items: center;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 22px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.bet-button {
  justify-self: end;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  padding: 12px 32px;
}

.bet_text {
  padding-right: 100px;
  line-height: 28px;
  word-spacing: 17px;
}
```

```html
<section class="cover overlay">
  <div class="cover_wrapper">
    <div class="ono_tebe_nado">
      <div class="aligned-text">О<span class="letter-spacing_60">но</span></div>
      <div class="aligned-text_center">те<span class="letter-spacing_60">бе</span></div>
      <div class="aligned-text_right"><span class="letter-spacing_60">н</span>ад<span class="letter-spacing_0">о</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="make_bet">
      <div class="bet-button">Сделать ставку</div>
      <div class="bet_text">Аукцион вещей, в которые никто не верил</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Или, как вариант, `margin-block: auto;` / `margin: auto 0;` (эффект будет тот же):

```css
.cover {
  height: 757px;
  color: #fff;
  background-image: url(https://i.ibb.co/s6kGSxv/cover.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
}

.cover_wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 530px;
  margin: 165px 50px 62px 50px;
}

.ono_tebe_nado {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 15px;
}

.letter-spacing_60 {
  letter-spacing: 60px;
}

.letter-spacing_0 {
  letter-spacing: 0px;
}

.aligned-text {
  display: flex;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 100px;
  line-height: 115%;
  letter-spacing: 30px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.aligned-text_center {
  display: flex;
  align-self: center;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 100px;
  line-height: 115%;
  letter-spacing: 30px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.aligned-text_right {
  display: flex;
  align-self: end;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 100px;
  line-height: 115%;
  letter-spacing: 30px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.make_bet {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  align-items: flex-end;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 22px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.bet-button {
  justify-self: end;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  padding: 12px 32px;
}

.bet_text {
  padding-right: 100px;
  line-height: 28px;
  word-spacing: 17px;
  /* new */
  /* margin-block: auto; */
  margin: auto 0;
}
```

```html
<section class="cover overlay">
  <div class="cover_wrapper">
    <div class="ono_tebe_nado">
      <div class="aligned-text">О<span class="letter-spacing_60">но</span></div>
      <div class="aligned-text_center">те<span class="letter-spacing_60">бе</span></div>
      <div class="aligned-text_right"><span class="letter-spacing_60">н</span>ад<span class="letter-spacing_0">о</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="make_bet">
      <div class="bet-button">Сделать ставку</div>
      <div class="bet_text">Аукцион вещей, в которые никто не верил</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Желаемого Вами эффекта можно добиться используя bootstrap. Может быть не точь в точь, но всё же

```css
.background-container {
  height: 757px;
  background-image: url(https://i.ibb.co/s6kGSxv/cover.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Ono tebe nado</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="background-container">
      <div class="row justify-content-start">
        <div class=col-4>
          <h1 class="text-white ms-5">ОНО</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class=col-4>
          <h1 class="text-white">ТЕБЕ</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row justify-content-end">
        <div class=col-4>
          <h1 class="text-white mb-5">НАДО</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row justify-content-around">
        <div class="col-8">
          <p class="fs-1 text-white lh-1 ms-5">Аукцион вещей, в которые никто не верил</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-4">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark fs-2 text-white lh-1">Сделать ставку</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-C6RzsynM9kWDrMNeT87bh95OGNyZPhcTNXj1NW7RuBCsyN/o0jlpcV8Qyq46cDfL" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```